# Перегрузка методов используя ключевое слово volatile

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Здрасьте. Изучаю многопоточное программирование и сейчас пытаюсь понять атомарность. В примере из книги за авторством Энтони Уильямса структура atomic_flag имеет 2 перегруженных метода.

```
bool test_and_set(memory_order _Order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile noexcept;
bool test_and_set(memory_order _Order = memory_order_seq_cst) noexcept;
```

Я создал свою структуру и сделал такую-же перегрузку. Вот она

```
struct foo {
    bool test() volatile noexcept { cout << "volatile"; return true; }
    bool test() noexcept { cout << "No volatile"; return true; }
};
```

При создании объекта и вызове метода test() нет никакой неоднозначности при вызове. Я не понимаю почему так происходит. Объясните пожалуйста

При вызове foo::test() в главном потоке в функции main вызывается метод без ключевого слова volatile.

Comment: Вы, похоже, сам объект класса foo объявили без квалификатора volatile. Поэтому никакой неоднозначности нет. То есть для объектов, объявленных с квалификатором volatile,будет вызываться соответствующий метод с volatile. А для объектов, объявленных без этого квалификатора, будет вызываться другой метод также без квалификатора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод с квалификатором volatile будет вызываться для объектов, объявленных также с квалификатором volatile. Иначе будет вызываться метод без квалификатора volatile.